# Deploy React Project made from scratch to GitHub pages. [Not using create-react-app]

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I've been looking for information in Google about how to deploy a React project to Github Pages, but all tutorials refers to deploying a React App (made using create-react-app and not a boilerplate from scratch).

Is there a hidden tutorial to do that?

Comment: Tyler Mcginnis has a react course that goes in to more detail about web pack and bable than anything else i have seen, but the course is not free. you can check out his website https://tylermcginnis.com/ https://stackoverflow.com/users/1867084/tyler-mcginnis

Comment: Hello @SteveBohmbach! Thank you for taking the time to comment my question. I've already bought a course at Udemy, just missing a couple of steps to deploy my project to GitHub pages. I'm going to wait to see if someone have found something useful, if not I have no alternative other than to buy the course.

Comment: Hello @SteveBohmbach I've just checked Tyler's Web page and I'm considering to buy the course, but before that I just want to confirm that he explain step by step the process of deploying to Git Hub pages React projects made from scratch. I will appreciate your guidance!

Comment: Now that i have looked back through the courses, he does not specifically go in to git hub pages. He just does a very good breakdown of creating react apps with out create-react-app. I apologize for miss understanding your question before.

Comment: Thank you @SteveBohmbach for clarifying this. I will keep searching! :)

Comment: Hello @SteveBohmbach! I just wanted to thank you for introducing me to Tyler's course, I've finally deployed my project (not in GH-Pages), and it worked like a charm! He has a beautiful way of explaining what is happening in the background. You made my week :) ha!

Comment: Im glad it was helpful. It really is a good course. Its great that you got it deployed!